# Как вести случайные строки из текстового файла?

Tags: файлы, ruby

Есть файл, задается число (допустим, n), из этого файла необходимо вывести n случайных строк. Помогите плиз.

Answer (score 1):

Сгенерировать n случайный чисел с диапазона `1 - кол-во_строк_в_файле`. Потом вывести заданные строки.

Но они будут не случайные, а псевдослучайные